# Reinstalling a game using Steam

Tags: steam

I recently downloaded a game on Steam (no more room in hell) and during the downloading it was interrupted due to a power outage. power was restored in a few minutes so I went back to Steam to try and redownload the game but it says that I can't. so I deleted the game off of my laptop and tried to download it again but it says that I already own the game and that it is in my game library; however when I checked my game library it wasnt there.

I restarted Steam and checked it again but it still didn't work. How do I redownload a game through Steam?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the client.blob file? (Make a back-up first, just in case)

Comment: @slow_excellence The client.blob is not used anymore since Steam updated their download technology. Anyway, OP, do you maybe have a filter on in your steam library? Make sure it is set to "Games" and not "installed" or something else. It should be there. If not, contact steam support.

Comment: Try verifying game cache.

Answer (score 4):

There should be `Play Now` button under the `xxx is already in your Steam library` in store page of the game. If the game is not installed on your computer, download screen should appear after clicking `Play Now`.

I don't own that particular game but let me show you with some other game. (which also is my favourite one)

[image: play now button]

After you cick that `Play Now` button, following screen should appear and you can install your game by clicking `next` etc..

[image: install screen]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do a "repair" on the game by either:

- clicking the "Delete local game content" and then trying to re-download the game OR
- clicking "Verify integrity of game cache" with the expectation that Steam should re-download any missing or corrupted files.

You can find these options by:

1. Right-clicking the game
2. Going to Properties
3. Going to the Local File tab

[image: Screenshot from Maximum-PC]